# mp4 files / SSTS info

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to find the fastest way to get a list of all I-frames in a movie.

So far, I tried ffprobe, but it is quite slow and I have been looking for a faster solution.

The other option I found is using the *mp4parser* tool; it outputs a file with this sectio, the SSTS info:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
/moov/trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stss                              @ 0x1c152d8
  Box size: 0x44    version: 0x0    flags: 0x0
  entry_count:              0xd
    sample_number:
     0x1    0x12d    0x259    0x385    ....
```

I can see that I have 13 I frames and they're spaced 300 frames apart (from the 4 values displayed)

Is the spacing of I frames constant through movies? or do I need to write my own SSTS parser to get the whole list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command below will quickly provide the timestamp for video keyframes along with other info.

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i in.mp4 -an -vf showinfo -f null -
```

Output looks like

```
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 00000000032903a0] n:  55 pts:5748224 pts_time:449.08  pos: 17288779 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:960x720 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:361866A6 plane_checksum:[BA2DCCBF A8E937B3 BD006225] mean:[220 117 133] stdev:[57.8 4.1 5.3]
```

The `pts_time` gets you the time index. The `n` is not accurate for absolute frame index, but it is an accurate count for keyframe index i.e. `n: 55` is the 56th keyframe in the video.